# Google Pay or Phone Pay or Paytm UPI API payout in Laravel

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, razorpay

I have a customer who have google pay or phone pay or paytm  account they give the details of phone number.

Now I need to withdraw the amount from there google pay or phone pay or paytm  account without using payment_link.

I could not find it in API Documentation . I want to know if this possible.

Is it possible with Razor pay API payment gateway integration.

I found this link useful But it is using JavaScript. can I do it in using  [Razor PAY PHP SDK](http://composer%20require%20razorpay/razorpay)
[Google Pay Checkout using Razor Pay](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payments/payment-methods/upi/google-pay/custom-checkout/)

Same way is it possible Phone Pay and Paytm Pay using Razor Pay

Comment: I used google pay directly using their [docs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial), though razor pay should be much easier

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about GPay, Paytm, PhonePe provides withdrawal API or Not. But RazorPay provides it. Please check [RazorpayX](https://razorpay.com/x/payouts/). I was used RazorPay's Payment Gateway as well as Withdrawals. it is very easy to integrate it

Refer [RazorPayX documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/razorpayx/payouts/)

**Updated:-** Paytm Now Provides Money Transfer API [See Docs link](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/api/bank-transfer-api/) ... when I was integrated paytm payment gateway at there time they was provides only payment gateway. but I check it today they provides more API Support for different different features. check it using above link. may be this one helps to you

I hope this one helps to you
Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer check it. if you have any query then fill to ask me